# Как подсчитать количество записей в выбранной базе MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Собственно вопрос:
Как подсчитать количество записей в выбранной базе MySQL?
Не могу найти как составить SQL запрос.
Дело в том, что phpMyAdmin это умеет делать, я тоже так хочу делать).
[image: phpMyAdmin]

Спасибо Alexander Zonov, дал направление куда копать: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286039/get-record-counts-for-all-tables-in-mysql-database/286048#286048
Там есть два интересных ответа:

```
SELECT SUM(TABLE_ROWS) 
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '{your_db}';
```

Этот запрос выдаёт какое-то не точное количество записей в выбранной базе, оно почему-то меньше.

```
SELECT table_name, table_rows
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '**YOUR SCHEMA**';
```

Этот запрос выводит список таблиц со значением количества строк:

```
table_name  table_rows  
table1      0
table2      0
table3      0
table4      0
table5      0
table6      46495
table7      0
table8      0
table9      0
table10     0
table11     1412
table12     0
table13     0
table14     0
table15     0
table16     1407
table17     3410
table18     0
table19     0
table20     0
table21     33360
```

Если выполнить запрос:

```
SELECT table_rows
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '**YOUR SCHEMA**';
```

То получаю столбец table_rows со значениями, от что нужно! Но, как теперь их суммировать?
SELECT SUM(table_rows); Выдаёт ошибку #1054 - Неизвестный столбец 'table_rows' в 'field list'.

Comment: тебе вот сюда: [Учебники и книги по MySQL](http://www.internet-technologies.ru/books/category_10.html)

Comment: Спасибо конечно) А написать сюда SQL запрос слабо? Или может тебе тоже туда надо, куда ты меня посылаешь)))? Я наверно перед тем как сюда написать не один день пробовал найти ответ. Я могу конечно в PHP посчитать в цикле количество записей в каждой таблице и суммировать. Но может есть какой-то проще вариант с помощью одного запроса?

Comment: @Romchik, это очень строго специализированный сайт, где эмоции мало уместны.

Comment: Запросом задачу не решить. Вот динамическим SQL в рамках ХП - вполне.

Comment: @Romchik на слабо берут не умных людей. У меня есть мозг, именно поэтому я и предлагаю самый оптимальный для тебя вариант на сегодня

Comment: @Romchik А почему посчитать в цикле на пхп для тебя не вариант? Phpmyadmin это и есть движок на php. Может там внутри также считается?

Comment: Алексей, я извиняюсь, что задел Ваш МОЗГ, но мне не нравятся советы людей, которые учат жизни и дают советы, куда-то посылают, а сами при этом ничего не знают. Я живу по принципу, если не знаешь точного ответа, то лучше промолчать, так будет умнее, потому что не ошибается тот, кто ничего не делает. Ну а я признаю, да, дурак, но зато у меня опыта больше)))

Comment: Alexander, извиняюсь, больше не буду.

Comment: @Romchik точный ответ был еще в первом комментарии. То, что тебе это не нравится - не делает его неправильным и неточным. Это всего лишь показывает, что кое кто на столько ленив, что не хочет прочитать книги и найти в них ответ. Что интересно, признаешься, что дурак, но не хочешь это исправить. Еще этим и хвалиться.. Печально.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не буду с Вами спорить, но именно здесь не было точного ответа от Вас или еще кого-то, а вот Alexander Zonov, не особо умничал, и дал хоть приблизительный, но более конструктивный ответ. Вы мне пытаетесь рассказать о книгах, где можно найти информацию. Это тоже самое, что сказать проживи жизнь, чтобы понять смысл жизни, на вопрос а в чем смысл жизни? Зчем тогда вообше рассказывать другим, живи себе молча и никому ничего не говори. Alexander Zonov мне подсказал направление, БОЛЬШЕ ему СПАСИБО!) И Вам Алексей спасибо, что указали мне на моё место, позже почитаю, как решу вопрос

Comment: @Romchik когда решите - не забудьте его опубликовать как ответ. Как минимум поделитесь знанием с другими.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский О.К. С удовольствием поделюсь своими знаниями с человечеством! Всегда так делаю!)

Comment: К сожалению, я не знаток SQL (плохо его помню), но нельзя ли написать  так `select sum (SELECT table_rows
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '**YOUR SCHEMA**')` ?

Comment: @avp да, спасибо, я этим запросом и считаю записи: SELECT SUM(TABLE_ROWS) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '{your_db}';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(TABLE_ROWS) 
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
     WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '{your_db}';
```

Взял из enSO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/286048

Дополнение. Как меня справедливо упрекают в комментариях, `TABLE_ROWS` - лишь оценочное количество записей.

На всякий случай, результат поиска командой

```
fgrep -r 'TABLE_ROWS' .
```

по корневой папке phpMyAdmin 4.4.6.1:

```
./libraries/server_databases.lib.php:            'SCHEMA_TABLE_ROWS',
./libraries/dbi/DBIDummy.class.php:            . ' `ROW_FORMAT` AS `Row_format`, `TABLE_ROWS` AS `Rows`,'
./libraries/dbi/DBIDummy.class.php:            'VERSION', 'ROW_FORMAT', 'TABLE_ROWS', 'AVG_ROW_LENGTH', 'DATA_LENGTH',
./libraries/dbi/DBIDummy.class.php:            . ' `ROW_FORMAT` AS `Row_format`, `TABLE_ROWS` AS `Rows`,'
./libraries/dbi/DBIDummy.class.php:            'TABLE_TYPE', 'ENGINE', 'VERSION', 'ROW_FORMAT', 'TABLE_ROWS',
./libraries/db_info.inc.php:                            'TABLE_ROWS' => 0,
./libraries/structure.lib.php:    if ($current_table['TABLE_ROWS'] > 0 || $table_is_view) {
./libraries/structure.lib.php:    if (isset($current_table['TABLE_ROWS'])
./libraries/structure.lib.php:    } // end if (isset($current_table['TABLE_ROWS'])) else
./libraries/structure.lib.php:        if ($current_table['TABLE_ROWS'] >= $GLOBALS['cfg']['MaxExactCountViews']
./libraries/structure.lib.php:        . PMA_Util::formatNumber($current_table['TABLE_ROWS'], 0);
./libraries/structure.lib.php:        // PBMS table in Drizzle: TABLE_ROWS is taken from table cache,
./libraries/structure.lib.php:        $current_table['TABLE_ROWS'] = PMA_Table::countRecords(
./libraries/structure.lib.php:        && $current_table['TABLE_ROWS'] < $GLOBALS['cfg']['MaxExactCount'])
./libraries/structure.lib.php:        || !isset($current_table['TABLE_ROWS'])
./libraries/structure.lib.php:        $current_table['TABLE_ROWS'] = PMA_Table::countRecords(
./libraries/DatabaseInterface.class.php:                                          AS `Rows`,-- TABLE_ROWS,
./libraries/DatabaseInterface.class.php:                                          AS `TABLE_ROWS`,
./libraries/DatabaseInterface.class.php:                    `TABLE_ROWS`         AS `Rows`,
./libraries/DatabaseInterface.class.php:                    $each_tables[$table_name]['TABLE_ROWS']
./libraries/DatabaseInterface.class.php:            $tables[$table_name]['TABLE_ROWS']
./libraries/DatabaseInterface.class.php:                        SUM(stat.NUM_ROWS)    AS SCHEMA_TABLE_ROWS';
./libraries/DatabaseInterface.class.php:                        SUM(t.TABLE_ROWS)      AS SCHEMA_TABLE_ROWS,
./libraries/DatabaseInterface.class.php:                    $databases[$database_name]['SCHEMA_TABLE_ROWS']      = 0;
./libraries/DatabaseInterface.class.php:                        $databases[$database_name]['SCHEMA_TABLE_ROWS']
./libraries/build_html_for_db.lib.php:    $column_order['SCHEMA_TABLE_ROWS'] = array(
./db_printview.php:        $sum_entries += $sts_data['TABLE_ROWS'];
./db_printview.php:        if (isset($sts_data['TABLE_ROWS'])) {
./db_printview.php:                echo PMA_Util::formatNumber($sts_data['TABLE_ROWS'], 0);
./db_printview.php:                echo PMA_Util::formatNumber($sts_data['TABLE_ROWS'], 0);
./db_structure.php:        $sum_entries += $current_table['TABLE_ROWS'];
./db_create.php:                'SCHEMA_TABLE_ROWS' => '0',
```

То есть PHPMyAdmin этим оценочным количеством все-таки пользуется.

Comment: Значения TABLE_ROWS есть всего лишь оценка количества записей, а не актуальное количество.

Comment: @Akina, да, действительно, это так для InnoDB, который как раз самый используемый, насколько я знаю. Тогда остается последовательный count, но автор вопроса в комментариях пишет, что это он и сам может. Да и тега языка у вопроса нет. С другой стороны, пользователю в интерфейсе можно показать и примерное количество записей. А для чего может потребоваться точное,  я и не представляю.

Comment: Этот запрос у меня выдаёт число "86084" а phpMyAdmin считает по другому = 86,815 Для села сойдёт)) Но хотелось бы по точнее)

Comment: @AlexanderZonov *для чего может потребоваться точное, я и не представляю* C разбивкой по таблицам - для оценки занимаемого пространства. А всего по БД - да, средняя температура по больнице.

Answer (score 3):

Это скорей не ответ а так, констатация факта, ну и моей невнимательности)
Как оказалось, что phpMyAdmin подсчитывает количество строк в базе неправильно и в этом сам признаётся (см.рис.) или у меня, что-то с самой базой не то, хотя все таблицы одинаковые. Решил проверить:

```
show table status;
```

Нашел столбец с количеством строк по каждой таблице, взял калькулятор в руки и сам посчитал, оказалось, что значение действительно отличается в меньшую сторону!
Стал использовать решение, которым буду пользоваться:

```
SELECT SUM(TABLE_ROWS) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '{your_db}';
```

Огромное спасибо Alexander Zonov и всем кто помогал мне. Проверил всё на практике, всё работает. Всем добра!)

[image: phpMyAdmin]

Answer (score -3):

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tablename`;

Comment: Это подсчёт записей в одной таблице базы а мне нужно посчитать количество строк во всех таблицах всей базы данных.

Comment: @Romchik Таблиц много?

Comment: Ну ты даёщь))) А изображение я прикрепил зачем?))) 21 таблица!) Ну я знаю как по отдельности посчитать потом сложить, но может есть вариант попроще.... Ну всёравно спасибо за ответ! Я ценю Ваше внимание и то время что вы мне уделили, спасибо!